# Isotope Container Resizing is Jarring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm creating a filterable portfolio with the javascript libary [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). I've centered the Isotope container in css via auto left and right margins,  and via the masonry layout [option](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#isfitwidth), `isFitWidth`, which "sets the width of the container to fit the available number of columns" (from Isotope docs).

**CSS**

```
#isotope-list {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item', 
    layoutMode : 'masonry',
    masonry: {
        isFitWidth: true,
        columnWidth: 60,
        gutter: 10
    },
    transitionDuration: '3s'
});
```

Unfortunately, when the isotope items are filtered, the container is immediatly resized before the transition is executed. This results in a jarring jump which you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tovly/eff841wh/). I've made the transition duration long so you can see the problem more easily.

I've tried adding a transition to the width of the container, `transition: width 3s ease;`, but that seems very laggy, jittery and jarring as well, even with easing. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tovly/b9va29dd/) is a jsfiddle with that transition applied.

What can I do to make the container resize non-jarring and not laggy while keeping the container centered?

Comment: I didn't notice a jarring effect in Chrome 40.0 for Mac. Maybe it's a browser issue.

Comment: @JustinMorgan I tested it in Chrome, IE and Firefox and I still notice the jump. It only occurs when the number of columns change as that is when the Isotope container is resized. It is more apparent when there are many items in the isotope grid. Here is a video showing the jumping effect: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OxMCWiLhrMdGZXNno5U0xiTDQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [.element-sizing](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing) and remove columnWidth and Gutter and just apply it with margins in your css. Also apply `float:left;` to your items.

There you go a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eff841wh/142/) for you.

Centered masonry:

use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) + [isotope element-sizing](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing) = http://jsfiddle.net/eff841wh/143/

Comment: How would you center the Isotope container with the method you mentioned? In the jsfiddle you posted the container is left aligned. @rob.m

Comment: @TovlyDeutsch I have updated my answer with centered masonry. But your question was in regards of the jumping when filter, centered masonry is another question and you should have asked it separately. Please accept my answer as it does answer your question. if you have other questions, create a new question.

Comment: The jsfiddle you posted seems to not completely center the isotope elements. Here is an example screeenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OxMCWiLhrMamhlNHZzX2dGazg/view?usp=sharing @rob.m

Comment: Also, I asked this question as one question because the method I am using to center the Isotope container is causing the jumping. If I disable `isFitWidth` the container will not be resized and there will be no jumping but the container will not be centered.

Comment: @TovlyDeutsch yet you haven't said on your question. Anyway I have provided you with an updated answer with the solution. Please accept.

Comment: The isotope items in the jsfiddle you posted aren't always centered as you can see in this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OxMCWiLhrMYjhXenZ3SkhVZ00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thats' normal, that's how it works. items are aligned left, what you want is an hack to re-center the items when you filter.

Comment: Exactly. And that's what I've partially already achieved. Unfortunately, the method I used to implement this "hack" is jarring and I was looking for a way to make it look smooth.

Comment: The new jsfiddle you posted uses the same method, `isFitWidth`, as I did in the original question and therefore still has that jarring jump on the container resize. Here is the same jsfiddle you posted but with a longer transition so it is easier to see the jump: http://jsfiddle.net/tovly/7ma23hL1/

Comment: i don't have any jarring effect to be honest. Anyway there you have the answer, if that's not what you are looking for. good luck with it